# I scared my kitten

Tags: cats, fear

So, I got a kitten about two weeks ago. Today I had to shave my legs, and she was scared of the electric razor. I didn't realize how scared she was and turned it off and moved it towards her. She hissed at it, and I had never heard her hiss before, so I left her alone and went back to shaving my legs. Afterwards I approached her and held my hand out to her, but she swatted me. I backed off and left her alone for a few hours, but the thing is, most of the time, my guardian wants me to keep her in my room, but after the incident I let her free roam the house for a bit, and she mostly followed me around. She was afraid of my hands for a bit, but even after a few hours she let me pet her again. But now she's afraid of my bed, specifically when I sit on my bed, since I shaved my legs on my bed. I don't know what to do now, it's almost time for bed, but I don't want her to be scared of me. She can't sleep anywhere else, my Guardian doesn't want her roaming the house at night, she has to be in my room. What do I do? Please note, if I had realized just how terrified she was, I would not have done what I did.

Comment: Give her some time, she will be fine sleeping in your room and find a place she deems safe to sleep on her own. Don't make too much of a fuzz about the situation, once you go to bed and fall asleep, it won't be long until she realizes there is no danger. After all, if there was danger, you would not fall asleep, right?

Comment: I took your advice and went to sleep. When I got in bed she was laying in her bed. When I woke up she was laying by my side in bed sound asleep. When she woke up she started purring and rubbing up against me.

Answer (score 2):

The best thing you can do is give her time and act as if nothing ever happened. She'll calm down eventually.

Your cat was frightened, but now she isn't sure if it was you, your bed or the razor that frightened her. You already gave her opportunities to see that your hand isn't frightening. Now all you have to do is give her opportunities to see that your bed isn't frightening. Let her approach the bed on her own terms, in her own time and she'll see that there is no reason to be afraid.